# Soundcloud API list my stream

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm using the JavaScript SDK for the Soundcloud API and trying to populate the top 10 tracks from authenticated users stream.

Currently I am implementing this with:

```
SC.get('/tracks', { limit: '10'}, function(tracks) {
   //Do stuff with tracks
});
```

However, this only returns the most recent 10 tracks/sounds uploaded to SoundCloud. Is there an easy way to populate my stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing, but there is no way to get the complete user's stream. You can get the users activities from

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities.json
```

But there are not **all** songs listed from your stream. I hope the SoundCloud devs will make that thing better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
fetch: function () {
    var self = this;
    SC.get("/tracks", { limit: '10'}, function (data) {
        self.tracks = $.map(data, function (track) {
            return {
                title: track.title
            };
        });
        self.attachTemplate();
    });
}

soundcloud.init({
    template: $('#tracks-template').html(),
    container: $('ul.soundcloud')
});
```

And show the item title in your HTML page.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't have a problem using that, but it just gives me the 10 most recent tracks added to soundcloud. However, I'm looking to get the top 10 from **my** stream(logged in user).

Comment: Oh, what do you mean by "top 10" ? Most played tracks ? Most popular ?

Comment: Sorry, I guess first 10 would be a better description. If you go to your soundcloud stream. I would like the first 10 tracks you see as you scroll down.